# Giving same classes unique identifyers to stop code repitition

Tags: javascript, css, class, repeat

I have this JS code

```
<script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').css('backgroundColor','#4c7fb5');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 2000);

});
</script>
```

The `.tile` class applies to all the buttons which are all called tile .

Is there any way to introduce a unique identifier without having to repeat this script for every button individually.

This is an example of the tile ref in the html

```
<a class="tile double bg-tile1color live animated flipInX" data-click="transform">
```

Comment: By "repeat this script" are you referring to `$(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");`?

Comment: `$(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");` -> `$(this).addClass("flipOutX");`

Comment: well at the moment I am anticipating to repeat the entire script but changing .tile to .tile2 .tile3 etc with the differences being the type of content loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use $(this), it applies only on the  element you clicked

```js
$('.tile').on('click', function() {

  $(this).addClass("flipOutX");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').css('backgroundColor', '#4c7fb5');
    $(".tile-group.main").css({
      marginLeft: "-40px",
      width: "1080px"
    }).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
  }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: ok thanks for that.... however if i am going to use different loads for different buttons i still need to identify them uniquely ?

Comment: Then you can just give them an ID. I'm not sure to understand your problem. Maybe you can add a fiddle and tell us what you try to achieve ?

Comment: no you are correct i need to give them an id so they retain their attributes of tile but are also unique... how would i give them an id ?

Comment: You can add a class and an ID at the same time, like this <a class="tile double bg-tile1color live animated flipInX" id="your-id" data-click="transform">

Comment: how would I reference that in the javascript though... would it be .tile .bg-tile1color

Comment: $('#your-id'). It would be easier if you provide a fiddle and explain what you are trying to do